# SparkSQL: Ignoring invalid json files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm loading a bunch of JSON files using SparkSQL, but some have problems.

I'd like to continue processing the other files whilst ignoring the bad files, how can I do that?

I tried using try-catch but it still fails. example:

```
try {
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext._

    val jsonFiles=sqlContext.jsonFile("/requests.loading")
} catch {
    case _: Throwable => // Catching all exceptions and not doing anything with them
}
```

I'm failing on:

```
14/11/20 01:20:44 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 3065.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6150, HDdata2, NODE_LOCAL, 1246 bytes)<BR>
14/11/20 01:20:44 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 3027.1 in stage 1.0 (TID 6130, HDdata2): com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing quote for a string value
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@753ab9f1; line: 1, column: 1805]
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's actually failing? These log entries are INFO and WARN lines respectively. Spark logging is very verbose, and these two lines don't convince me that the exception isn't being caught. If I saw an ERROR line it would be different, but personally I'd put a `println` into the catch body to be sure.

Comment: Yes i'm positive that it's failing.
I first took care of it by filtering out the bad jsons but then I was told that version 1.2 can now ignore malformed json strings, so I switched to 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spark 1.2, Spark SQL will handle those broken JSON records for you. Here is an example...

```
// requests.loading has some broken records
val jsonFiles=sqlContext.jsonFile("/requests.loading")
// Look at the schema of jsonFiles, you will see a new column called "_corrupt_record", which holds all broken JSON records
// jsonFiles.printSchema
// Register jsonFiles as a table
jsonFiles.registerTempTable("jsonTable")
// To query all normal records
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM jsonTable WHERE _corrupt_record IS NULL")
// To query all broken JSON records
sqlContext.sql("SELECT _corrupt_record FROM jsonTable WHERE _corrupt_record IS NOT NULL")
```